# MySQL 2 counts in query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this table, answers:

| user | question | rightAnswer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab | 1 | 0 |
| bc | 1 | 1 |
| de | 1 | 1 |
| bc | 2 | 1 |
| ab | 2 | 1 |
| de | 2 | 0 |
| fx | 2 | 1 |

I want to create a view in phpMyAdmin that can display the question number, the total number of answers to that question and the number of right answers to that question.
I would like it to look like:

| question | total answers | right answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |

Could anyone help me to make this view? How do I create the query? I have tried something about count(*) where rightAnswer=1, but I cannot get it to count BOTH the total number of answers and the number of answers of each question.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
select question,count(*),sum(rightAnswer)
from TABLE
group by question
order by question
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select question, count(*) as total_answers, sum(rightAnswer) as right_answers
from your_table
group by question
order by question
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ms sql syntax:

```
SELECT Question, totalAnswers.Total, rightAnswers.correct
FROM answers AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Question, COUNT(rightanswer) AS correct
    FROM answers
    WHERE rightanswer = 1
    GROUP BY Question
) rightAnswers
ON a.Question = rightAnswers.QUestion
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Question, COUNT(rightanswer) AS total
    FROM answers
    GROUP BY Question
) totalAnswers
ON a.Question = rightAnswers.QUestion
```